# Return boolean on mysql select statment after comparing values of particular column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a module table which has weightage and course id columns. Multiple modules with different weights can be added to a course. I need to compare the weights of all modules added to a course and return true if all weights are equal, false otherwise.

```
id   name   weight   course_id
 1    A       30       112
 2    B       40       112
 3    C       20        87
 4    D       23        87
 5    E       10        97
 6    F       10        97
```

I need the select query to return true if the weights for the modules(E and F), added to the course with id 97  are equal, false otherwise

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the parameters you want to use?

Comment: There will be only 1 parameter to the query, ie course id

Comment: Ok. Can you see if my method also works?

Comment: @Madhivanan, sorry for the late reply. Your method is also correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I need to compare the weights of all modules added to a course and return true if all weights are equal, false otherwise*

**Try this**:

```
select 
  course_id, count( distinct weightage ) = 1 as matched
from my_table
group by course_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method

```
select 
  course_id, 1 as matched
from my_table
group by course_id
Having min(weight)=max(weight)
```